# Unable to Bind ObservableCollection from MVVM to ListView in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to bind the List View to Observable Collection of a class and for some reason, the DisplayMemberBinding attribute of GridViewColumn is not binding to the content of collection.
    If I use ListView.ItemTemplate, everything works fine. But I need the data in the form of a grid, so I am using GridView inside ListView.View.

First Image, Image 1 is the AssessmentSummaryList content in debug mode.
Second Image, Image 2 is the final output shown on the screen. The content from the list is not binding to the GridViewColumn.

These are the two view models I am using:

```
public class AssessmentSummaryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public string Question { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public string SelectedOption { get; set; }

    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class AssessmentViewModel : BaseViewModel 
{
    private ObservableCollection<AssessmentSummaryViewModel> assessmentSummaryList;

    public ObservableCollection<AssessmentSummaryViewModel> AssessmentSummaryList
    {
        get { return assessmentSummaryList; }
        set
        {
            assessmentSummaryList = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("AssessmentSummaryList");

        }
    } 

    public void SetNextAssessment()
    {
       AssessmentSummaryList= Service.GetAssessmentSummary(ApplicationModel.SelectedModule.Id,    
         ApplicationModel.SelectedUtility.Id); //the service returns ObservableCollection<AssessmentSummaryViewModel> data
      var EndScreen = new AssessmentSummaryView(); //Setting the last screen to AssessmentSumamryView, this will be called dynamically from other UserControl Xaml Page
    }
}
```

AssessmentSummaryView Xaml Code is as follows:

```
<ListView x:Name="lstvSummary1" Grid.Row="2" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AssessmentSummaryList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
<ListView.View>
            <GridView ColumnHeaderContainerStyle="{StaticResource myHeaderStyle}">
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}" Width="200">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Design Element" />
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Question}" Width="400">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Question" />
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SelectedOption}" Width="300">
                    <GridViewColumnHeader Content="Response" />
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
</ListView>
```

AssessmentSummaryView Code-behind is as follows:

```
public partial class AssessmentSummaryView : UserControl
{
    public AssessmentSummaryView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Comment: worked on mine, did the item list appear at all? if not then it's mostlikely you havent bind the datacontext of the usercontrol to the vm

Comment: @dnr3: The code I posted is exactly how I have in my application. I edited the question to include the images of the content of the list in debug mode and the final output shown on the screen. The GridViewColumn is not getting the content from the list.

Comment: hmm yeah you already get the list, not sure what happened here, it shows the propertes value on mine

Comment: @dnr3: Did you have to do anything different or you just tried this piece of code?

Comment: i just tried ur code, the difference only the SetNextAssessment() which i scratched out and put add some dummy data on the vm constructor.

Comment: Its work fine in my case too. Can you try to decompose the issue and provide more concrete example?

Comment: Working here too. If I were you, I would attach WPF Inspector and play with the binding property, the problem has to be in there.

Comment: DataContext.AssessmentSummaryList really

Comment: @All: Believe it or not, I did no changes to my code but still it worked. Ask me how? I just put some style for the ItemContainerStyle of ListView and boom it worked. Again my elements do not bind to the properties of list if I remove the ItemContainerStyle for the ListView. What do I have in my ItemContainerStyle??? Nothing just the "BorderThickness" set to "1" and "BorderBrush" set to "Black". Thank you all for your time and help. I am voting everyone's post to   useful. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @Mark Homer: Yes you are right. "DataContext.AssessmentSummaryList" do works.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=DataContext.AssessmentSummaryList, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}">
<ListView.View>
    <GridView>
        <GridView.Columns>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Design Element" Width="200" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Title}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Question" Width="400" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=Question}"/>
            <GridViewColumn Header="Response" Width="300" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=SelectedOption}"/>
        </GridView.Columns>
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```